# cannot download lxml on windows

Tags: python, lxml, libxml2, python-docx

So I am trying to download lxml for windows because it is required for python-docx.  I tried everything but nothing seems to work.  Specifically, when I run `py -m pip install lxml`, I get the following error: `Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2`.

Is `libxml2` installed?

I tried to install `libxml2` and failed.  I looked at other questions but have not managed to install anything with `.whl`.  Apparently, `libxml2` is a C++ library and is not recognized by pip.  How do I install `libxml2` then?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing one of the Windows binaries from here:

ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/

The file you'll probably need is `libxml2-2.7.8.win32.zip`. There are executable files in the `bin` directory of the zip file.